# Is there any wearable device art generator?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have finished my first Android watch face and I'd like to prepare some simple promo graphics.
When it comes to normal Android application I can get screenshot and use Device Art Generator from android developer web pages https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html to place it within a real phone image. But this page does not offer wearable art. There are no watches to pick.
Are you aware of similar option anywhere on the web? I mean either similar web pages where I can pick a device and place screenshot of my watch face in it or a Photoshop design file which I can use to do the same. I'm looking for round devices art (Moto 360 or LG G Watch R), but would be thankful even for square devices.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples throughout the third party community, although none made specifically by Google at this point.

A good start is [this square frame](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/07/31/android-wear-flat-device-frame/) and a [matching round frame](https://plus.google.com/+DanieleBonaldo/posts/CfzUWFEx9w8).

Answer (score 2):

[Device Art Generator](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html) now has the option to add device art for Android Wear. You can generate round and square images too.